# Backup Ubuntu Software and Wipe Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, software-installation, paths

Hello I am new to Ubuntu. I Installed a bunch of softwares like Android Studio and JDK and other stuff. Now my ubuntu is messed up and It doesn't show the login screen and when I start lightdm and put my password it does not login to my desktop. (this happened after messing with my graphic driver and installing Nvidia graphic driver I think) So I want to wipe linux cause I do not care about the OS but I want to keep settings that I did for Android (path and etc.) and also I want to back up my software so I can easily recover them on the fresh Ubuntu that I am going to install. I know I my question has many parts. What is the solution for keeping the settings , backing up the softwares (but not the graphic driver) and wiping out the Ubuntu.

Comment: Don't back up software; make a list of your favourite applications and reinstall them. Your settings will be in /home/username.

Comment: but Android studio is pretty heavy to download again plus I added lots of SDK stuff to it so it would't be a good idea to re-download all of it again.

Comment: @MohsenFM - If you manually installed Android Studio, it should be in a single directory (I think the default is ~/android-studio). When you run Android Studio for the first time, it will download the Android SDK/Tools to ~/Android. All of your settings and AVDs will be kept in ~/.android. You can tar up each of those directories and copy them somewhere, then restore them when you re-install Ubuntu. For example, you could tar up all three at once using: `tar -czvf androidstudio.tar.gz ~/.android ~/Android ~/android-studio` - then just copy `androidstudio.tar.gz` to a USB key (or wherever).